# can't add id with variable to classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I iterate over class names, I can't `wrap`, nor add `id+var` for them, here is the problem:

`$('.meteo')` returns a `list`, so, `$('.meteo')[0]` will return the first element, but why then can't I manipulate it in a loop? for example:

```
for (h = 0; h < 4; h++) {
    $('.meteo')[h].attr('id', 'meteo'+h);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using a jQuery method, `.attr()`, on a non-[jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

`$('.meteo')[0]`, becomes a native [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), and it doesn't have jQuery methods.

You could use the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access the the element by its index instead:

```
$('.meteo').eq(h).attr('id', 'meteo' + h);
```

---

You may also be able to change the `id` property directly:

```
$('.meteo')[h].id = 'meteo' + h;
```

or..

```
document.querySelectorAll('.meteo')[h].id = 'meteo' + h;
```

Comment: that did the job! wonderful! sorry am beginner in jquery, i always liked work with simple javascript (bases)

Comment: awww! you just gave me the way to do it on plain javascript, this is where i see myself knowing nothing about it :D

Answer (score 2):

The items in the returned jQuery set are native `DOMElements` you need to rewrap them like

`$($('.meteo')[h]).attr('id', 'meteo'+h);`

or use the native [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method like so:

**Native only:**

```
var metro = document.querySelectorAll('.metro'), i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    metro[i].setAttribute('id', 'metro'+i);
```

Comment: @Abdelouahab yes it is, using `eq` is a little bit faster.

Comment: ah, then I will use `eq`, or going back to plain javascript :D

Comment: @Abdelouahab the real overhead is in rematching inside the loop ;) You should match outside the loop (be it native or jquery) and iterate the returned set. As it is now you're rematching each iteration.

Comment: now that i am almost done in the work, i found that it was a better idea of me if i learned a little bit of Angular, because it is really heavy job using plain jquery :(

Comment: @Abdelouahab I've updated my answer showing native only with "outer loop set matching". The use of your frameworks and libraries is up to you, angular may be too much. If you're targeting modern browsers you could do without jQuery and just use modern features.

Comment: @LJ it seems that i have to learn a lot about javascript again :D thank you ^_^